# How can find custom tag inside text in php

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I looking for PHP solution, I have some HTML content with some custom tag like

```
$html = "he approaches very silently towards him but at the last point of time, the man gets the hint and manages to escape from the attack. ,
[vid] youtubeURL/watch?time_continue=58&v=eED6VRcj1Rs [/vid] What happens in the latter is just breath-taking and comes with a reason why this video has gone viral in such short span of time";
```

**I want Output of just below mention text only :**

```
[vid] youtubeURL/watch?time_continue=58&v=eED6VRcj1Rs [/vid]

   or
[vid] youtubeURL/watch?time_continue=58&v=eED6VRcj1Rs [Endvid]
```

$FWithReplaceWord will be youtube  "v=" ID **eED6VRcj1Rs**

**Need output**

```
<div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 vid1'><iframe class='embed-responsive-item' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/$FWithReplaceWord' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

**I am using**

```
preg_match_all('~([vid](.*?)[/vid])~', $html, $matches);
```

But its not working. Please help me out.

Comment: You're wanting the array?

Comment: If you only want to turn `[vid]` into `[vid class="vid1"]` why don't you use a simple `str_replace`, you don't need to describe all until the closing tag?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte want to convert that text into <div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9'><iframe class='embed-responsive-item' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/$FWithReplaceWord' allowfullscreen></iframe></div> so want v=eED6VRcj1Rs value from youtube url

Comment: Ok, in this case using `preg_match_all` is useless, use `preg_replace` instead and play with capturing groups. Keep in mind that `[` is a special character in a regex (that opens a character class) and to figure a literal `[` you need to escape it with a backslash.

Comment: If you are in a more sophisticated mood, you can also use `preg_replace_callback` to extract the query part of you urls with `parse_url`.

Comment: You have not shown any example that is not working. You need to provide that at least otherwise it's totally not clear what your question is. It does not work out of thin air, but I guess you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example with `preg_replace_callback` (stronger approach):

```
$str = <<<'EOD'
[vid] youtubeURL/watch?time_continue=58&v=eED6VRcj1Rs [/vid]
   or
[vid] youtubeURL/watch?time_continue=58&v=eED6VRcj1Rs [Endvid]
EOD;

$format = '<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 vid1"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/%s" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';

$result = preg_replace_callback('~\Q[vid]\E \s* ([^[\s]+) \s* \Q[/vid]\E~x',
    function ($m) use ($format) { 
        foreach (explode('&', parse_url($m[1], PHP_URL_QUERY)) as $param) {
             list($key, $value) = sscanf($param, '%[^=]=%s');
             if ($key == 'v') return sprintf($format, $value);
        };
        return $m[0];
    }, $str);

echo $result;
```

With `preg_replace` only (but a more naive approach):

```
$str = <<<'EOD'
[vid] youtubeURL/watch?time_continue=58&v=eED6VRcj1Rs [/vid]
   or
[vid] youtubeURL/watch?time_continue=58&v=eED6VRcj1Rs [Endvid]
EOD;

$replacement = '<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 vid1"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/$1" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';

$result = preg_replace('~\Q[vid]\E \s* [^[\s]+ [?&] v=([^[&\s]+) \s* \Q[/vid]\E~x', $replacement, $str);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 5):

## Logic

```
<?php

$html = "he approaches very silently towards him but at the last point of time, the man gets the hint and manages to escape from the attack. , [vid] youtubeURL/watch?time_continue=58&v=eED6VRcj1Rs [/vid] What happens in the latter is just breath-taking and comes with a reason why this video has gone viral in such short span of time";

function getBetweenTwoStrings ($string, $start, $end) {
 $string = " ".$string;
 $ini = strpos($string, $start);
 if ($ini == 0) return "";
 $ini += strlen($start);
 $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
 return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

// Assuming you need in array as well
$tag[0] = "[vid]";
$tag[1] = getBetweenTwoStrings($html, "[vid]", "[/vid]");
$tag[2] = "[/vid]";

echo $tag[0];
echo $tag[1];
echo $tag[2];

?>
```

## Output:

```
[vid] youtubeURL/watch?time_continue=58&v=eED6VRcj1Rs [/vid]
```

## Note:

```
Now you can play around the way you want the output.
```

Answer (score 2):

If i were you,I would try something like this:

```
preg_match_all("/(\[vid\])(.*?)(\[\/vid\])/s", $html, $tag);
```

In this case, assumming that you have ONE occurence of the tags and the content, you will able to access them with $tag[1][0], $tag[2][0] and $tag[3][0] which in your example will have values:

```
$tag[1][0] = "[vid]";
$tag[2][0] = "youtubeURL/watch?time_continue=58&v=eED6VRcj1Rs ";
$tag[3][0] = "[/vid]";
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to to match [vid] tags with classes in them(e.g[vid class="vid1"]), then you will need to change your regex to this:

```
preg_match_all("/(\[vid.*\])(.*?)(\[\/vid\])/s", $html, $tag);
```

Comment: @g-margaritis output comming : Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: Why using the m modifier?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte preg_match_all("/(\[vid\])(.*)(\[\/vid\])/", $html, $tag); the output is same

Comment: @sanjeev are you sure that your tags are exactly as in your example?or you added a class to the tags?e.g.[vid class="vid1"] youtubeURL/watch?time_continue=58&v=eED6VRcj1Rs [/vid]

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte I am using the m modifier for matching across multiple lines and the U modifier for ungreedy matching

Comment: You misunderstood what the m modifier does. The m modifier doesn't allow the dot to match newlines, the m modifier only changes the meaning of the `^` and `$` anchors from "start of the string" and "end of the string" to "start of the line" and "end of the line". To allow the dot to match newline, you need to use the s modifier, but I don't think it's the problem here. About the U modifier, it's a bit a useless feature (in particular when you have only one quantifier in the pattern).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, all though it is not required. so in case it is not possible. we can let it be

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte About the m modifier you are right.However if there are more than one pair of tags, then we will need the U modifier because otherwise the expression is going to match everything between the first opening tag in the subject string up to the last closing tag in the subject string,which we dont wan't. Anyway.If there is only one pair of tags, I agree that the U modifier should be ommitted

Comment: When I say that U isn't a very useful feature, I mean that writing a lazy quantifier with a question mark isn't more complicated (and less error prone for other readers).

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte Ok now.I removed m and U modifiers and left just the s in case there are line breaks between the tags